# Where to get historical daily settlement price of each VSTOXX futures contract

Tags: futures

I'm doing some analysis on VIX and VSTOXX futures and require historical prices of each contract as a result. VIX info is free to download on CBOE website: http://cfe.cboe.com/products/historicalvix.aspx. Basically I can download daily settlement price for each VIX future contract ever traded. I am trying to find the same for VSTOXX but not see it anywhere on Eurexchange. I placed a request but was told I need to place an order. Is that true? where can I find such info. I do not mind paying but just want to get more info.
Regards,
Li

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you'd need to place a data order in data shop on [Eurexchange](http://datashop.deutsche-boerse.com/2001/en). The problem: You can't select a single instrument (like VSTOXX), but you are getting all traded options and futures series.
2. Alternatively, if you are an institutional investor, you could buy a data cut from OptionMetrics.
3. Lastly, you could write a parser and grab the prices [online](http://www.eurexchange.com/exchange-en/market-data/clearing-data/settlement-prices), but that won't include historical prices (only going forward).

Answer (score 1):

You can get them, either adjusted from [barcharts](https://www.quandl.com/data/BCEUX?filterSelection=all&keyword=VSTOXX&page=3) or raw from [quandle](https://www.quandl.com/data/CHRIS/EUREX_FVS1-VSTOXX-Futures-Continuous-Contract-1-FVS1-Front-Month)